# Use ObservableCollection<T> as an attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf

Since I don't want to create a different attached property for every ObservableCollection, where T can be any of my personal logic classes, I was wondering if it is possible to be more generic.

To be more specific, when using DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached I would like the owner type to be ObservableCollection.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of where you would want to use this? The answer will really differ depending on whether you are trying to create a custom control, or some other type of object.

Comment: I want to create an attached property that binds an observable collection <T>

Comment: and since you can't create the attached property class as of type T ( I assume, since how would the xaml create your concrete type), there is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but then you will need to create a concrete class for each type. This will solve the issue you are saying you have - i.e.

> Since I don't want to create a different attached property for every
>   ObservableCollection,

This solves this issue (you have only one attached property). But you still need a single line that will define the concrete type by manner of inheritance.

```
public class X<T>
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> GetCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<T>)obj.GetValue(CollectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCollection(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<T> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CollectionProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Collection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Collection", typeof(ObservableCollection<T>), typeof(X<T>), new PropertyMetadata(null));


}

public class XInt : X<int> { }
```

And then in XAML:

```
<Grid local:XInt.Collection="{Binding}">

</Grid>
```

If you could explain more clearly what it is you are trying to do (i.e. why do you need the attached property to be of a certain type), there could be better solutions for this. For example - why not have the type be IList and then cast to IList or IEnumerable or INotifyCollectionChanged according to the functionality you require).